# Angular2: Row deleted after form reset

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have a table of students with CRUD operation. For each row I have an Edit button

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead class="studentHeader">
    <tr>
      <td>Roll Number</td>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="let student of studentList;let i=index">
      <td>{{student.rollNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{student.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{student.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{student.gender}}</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="editStudent(student)">Edit</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And the modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
        <form #studentForm="ngForm" novalidate>
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Add Student</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <label path="rollnumber"  class="sr-only">Roll Number</label>
              <input type="text" id="rollNum" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.rollNumber" name="rollnumber" placeholder="Student Roll Number" required autofocus /><br>
              <label path="firstName"  class="sr-only">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="Student First Name" required /><br>
              <label path="lastName"  class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="Student Last Name" required />
              <h5><span class="label label-default">Gender</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.gender">
                <label for="male">Male</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.gender">
                <label for="female">Female</label><br>
              </h5>
 </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="addStudent(studentObj)" *ngIf="studentAdd">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" *ngIf="studentUpdate" (click)="updateStudent(studentObj)">Update</button>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Component

```
@ViewChild('studentForm') studentForm: NgForm;
  private studentList: Array<StudentDto> = [];
  private studentObj: StudentDto = {};
  private departmentList: Array<string> = ["Computer Science", "Information Science", "Electronics", "Mechanical", "Civil"];
  private studentAdd: boolean = true;
  private studentUpdate: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.studentList = StudentData;
  }

  private addStudent(addStudentObj: StudentDto): void {
    this.studentList.push(addStudentObj);
    this.studentForm.reset();
  }

  private editStudent(editStudentObj: StudentDto): void {
    this.studentAdd = false;
    this.studentUpdate = true;
    this.studentObj = Object.assign({}, editStudentObj);
  }

  private updateStudent(updateStudentObj: StudentDto): void {
    for(let i:number = 0; i<this.studentList.length; i++){
      if(this.studentList[i].rollNumber == updateStudentObj.rollNumber){
        this.studentList[i] = updateStudentObj;
      }
    }
    this.studentForm.reset();

  }
```

After adding/updating a student I want to reset the modal to empty. But if do studentForm.reset(), particular row which I edit gets deleted from the table. How to reset the modal without deleting row from table?

Comment: you need to take the updated model and set it to the existing model before resetting

Comment: @RahulSingh I'm adding/updating the array by after taking modal data and at last doing form reset but it's not working

Comment: by not working what do you mean

Comment: @Protagonist You need to use FormArray take a look at https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray and here is Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/hQ6RtzCfPosfQl4HlbZQ?p=preview

Comment: after resetting you want the form array to persisit ?

Comment: @RahulSingh First I want to add a student object and after clicking edit student modal is persisting previous student object. So in addStudent() method, after pushing to the array I did form reset. But its adding empty row to the table

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with a form and a table, and the reason is the two way binding you're using. The solution for me was to use one way binding. You need to change this `[(ngModel)]` for this `[ngModel]`. Remove the parentheses.

```
<input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" [ngModel]="studentObj.lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="Student Last Name" required />
```